# Generating rectangle centered by point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, polygon-creation, rectangle

I have a layer which contains points. The layer has `"height"` and `"width"` attributes.

I need rectangles around those points, but a point should be in the center of the related rectangle whose height and width value comes from the point attributes.

Is there any tool?

[image]

Example data for three points:

```
height   width
20       12
6        10
4        14
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Check the ["Rectangles, Ovals, Diamonds"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#rectangles-ovals-diamonds) geoalgorithm in the QGIS's Processing Toolbox (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

[image: example]

Answer (score 21):

There is ["Geometry by Expression"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#geometry-by-expression) tool. You should use in a [Projected Coordinate System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projected_coordinate_system).

- Select "Polygon" as "Output geometry type" option.
- Click "Expression" button (highlighted blue square)
- And paste the following expression

  ```
  make_rectangle_3points(
    make_point($x + "height"/2, $y + "width"/2),
    make_point($x - "height"/2, $y + "width"/2),
    make_point($x - "height"/2, $y - "width"/2)
  )
  ```

[image]

Result:

[image]